# Proper way of determining if there is connection to a firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

```
func checkForConnection()  {
        let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
        connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool , connected {
                print("Camera View Connected")
                self.connectionStatus = 1
                self.UpdateConnection()
            } else {
                print("Camera View Not connected")
                self.connectionStatus = 0
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(2.0), target: self, selector: #selector(CameraViewController.UpdateConnection), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        })
    }

    func UpdateConnection()  {
        let connectionBanner = Banner(title: "Connection Error", subtitle: "Tap to dismiss", image: UIImage(named: "Wi-Fi"), backgroundColor: UIColor(hexString: "#DA4167"))
        if connectionStatus == 0 {
            print("connection banner shown from camera view")
            // What happens when there's no connection

            connectionBanner.dismissesOnTap = true
            connectionBanner.show(duration: 10)
        }

        else if connectionStatus == 1 {
            connectionBanner.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Here I have a code which detects if the app has connection to the database. If it doesn't, it will display a banner notification telling the user that he has lost connection. But on first install, it always displays no connection despite having connection.

I understand the app takes awhile to establish connection but is there a way to implement a retry before calling the banner? I've already set it such that even when there's no connection, it will delay before executing the banner if connectionState is still = 0.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Here's my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {



        // for connection 
        checkForConnection()
}
```

There's only one function here to check for connection.

Comment: Does your banner change after some time after your first install?

Comment: Nope it doesn't it's supposed to be the same banner, only displaying when the user lacks connectivity.

Comment: Are you calling *update connection* or *checkForConnection* in your viewDidLoad? If yes update your code with that code block

Comment: Yes I called it in viewDidLoad. Oh, which code block do you mean?

Comment: viewDidLoad block

Comment: Hmm wouldn't that cause a loop if I call viewdidload upon detection of server connection?

Comment: No, update your question with `viewDidLoad` block.

Comment: Done updated, there's only one function there to checkForConnection